# Django templates: How do I use a field in the model in a template?

Tags: django, django-templates

In this template,

```
<body><p>You searched for: <strong>{{ first }} {{ last }}</strong></p>

{% if lawyers %}
    <p>There are {{ lawyers|length }} schoolmates of <strong>{{ first }} {{ last }}</strong> in the database:</p>
    <ul>
        {% for lawyer in lawyers %}
        <li> {{ lawyer.first }} {{ lawyer.last }} {{ lawyer.firm_name }} {{ lawyer.school }} {{ lawyer.year_graduated }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% else %}
    <p><strong>{{ first }} {{ last }}</strong> has no classmates in the database. Try another lawyer.</p>
{% endif %}
```

I pick up `{{ first }}`  and `{{ last }}` from the search form but not the other parameters such as `year_graduated`.

But I want to be able to say:

```
<p>You searched for: <strong> {{ first }} {{ last }}, class of {{ year_graduated }} </strong> </p>
```

How can I use `lawyer.year_graduated` in the template even though it is not in the search form?

See [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103507/django-queryset-api-how-do-i-join-iexact-and-icontains) for the view function.

Thank you.

Comment: What if `laywer.year_graduated` isn't the same in all results? It looks like you are implying that `year_graduated` is a search parameter?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I use this only in the case when the result returns the schoolmates of the query. When there are more than 1 lawyer with same name I use the query only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the easy way would just be to add year_graduated to the context dict.

```
return render_to_response('search_results.html', {'lawyers': lawyers1, 'last': last_name, 'first': first_name, 'year_graduated': q_year[0], 'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole view could use some work to make things a little easier on yourself. Here are a few quick changes (including the ones discussed in the other question):

```
def search_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search_form = SearchForm(request.POST)
        if search_form.is_valid():
            last_name = search_form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            first_name = search_form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            fields = {}
            if last_name:
                lawyers = fields['last__iexact'] = last_name
            if first_name:
                lawyers = fields['first__icontains'] = first_name
            try:
                searched_lawyer = Lawyer.objects.get(**fields)
            except Lawyer.DoesNotExist:
                form = SearchForm()
                return render_to_response('not_in_database.html', {'last': last_name, 'first': first_name, 'form': form})
            except Lawyer.MultipleObjectsReturned:
                form = SearchForm(initial={'last_name': last_name})
                # Note: this breaks the current multiple returns functionality, up to you...
                return render_to_response('more_than_1_match.html', {'last': last_name, 'first': first_name, 'form': form}) 
            q_school = searched_lawyer.school
            q_year = searched_lawyer.year_graduated
            classmates = Lawyer.objects.filter(school__iexact=q_school).filter(year_graduated__icontains=q_year).exclude(last__icontains=last_name)
            form = SearchForm()
            return render_to_response('search_results.html', {'classmates': classmates, 'searched_lawyer': searched_lawyer, 'form': form})
    else:
        form = SearchForm()
        return render_to_response('search_form.html', {'form': form, })
```

So now rather than using "first" and "last" in your template, you'd be using "searched_lawyer.first", etc.. (But this means you would have access to all the attributes of that lawyer in your template)

Comment: Looks good. I'll study this in detail and implement when I understand it. Thank you for the help.